# can i uninstall ubuntu 14.04 unity desktop environment and replace it with paper-gtk

Tags: 14.04, unity, gtk, desktop-environments

I'm a Linux newbie... the first Linux OS I started using is Ubuntu 14.04.02 LTS and to be honest, I really don't like the Unity desktop environment that ships with Ubuntu so I was wondering if I could replace the unity desktop with something that takes up less system resources like *Paper GTK*.

So how do I replace the Unity DE with *Paper GTK*?

I am talking about something like the picture in the link below....

[image: example screenshot]

Comment: A GTK theme does not make a Desktop Enviroment.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a Gnome Shell theme, so I suggest the a combination of

1. [How do I install and use the latest version of GNOME?](/q/22946/175814) (meaning Gnome Shell)
2. [How to install themes with GNOME tweak tool?](/q/101651/175814)
3. [How can you remove Unity?](/q/6302/175814) (optionally)

Comment: If you prefer Gnome Shell over Unity you can install [Ubuntu GNOME](http://ubuntugnome.org/) version instead of "official" release.

Comment: can i install gnome desktop environment?

Comment: Step 1 will install Gnome Shell, but not the entire Gnome Desktop Environment. Ubuntu uses mostly the same default applications as GDE and you can install the remainder through packages.

Comment: Regarding of "something that takes up less system resources like Paper GTK." notice than both Unity and Gnome-shell use about the same resources.

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: if this answers your question, don't forget to click the grey ☑ under the "0" at the left of this text to [accept it](/help/someone-answers), which means "yes, this answer is valid"!